# Verilog: XOR all signals of vector together

Tags: verilog

Say I'm given a vector `wire large_bus[63:0]` of width 64. How can I XOR the individual signals together without writing them all out:

`assign XOR_value = large_bus[0] ^ large_bus[1] ^ ... ^ large_bus[63]` ?

I'm especially interested in doing this for vectors where the width is specified by a `localparam`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Binary operators like &, |, ^ and some others can also be unary in verilog, which is quite convenient. They perform bitwise operations on the operand and return a single bit value. See e.g. [reduction operators](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html) on asic-world.com.

```
reg [63:0] large_bus;

wire xor_value;
assign xor_value = ^large_bus;
```